# How to restrict an app to make changes in a folder?

Tags: files, system-apps, delete

There is an app that sucks my tablet and i don't won't to delete it. This app causes a huge trouble for me. I have granted it Storage Permission. But the apps also deletes some other folders, I want to restrict it from happening.

Comment: You should be more precise and name the app you have problems with. May be the community knows alternatives so that you can delete the problematic app.

Answer (score 1):

Restricting an app from writing storage in modern Android is just impossible. In specially Android 4.4.4 it was possible by the Application Permissions option that was in Settings. In the modern Android, when you install an app it assumes you explicitly agreed it's permissions before the actual app installation